# Site can't be reached error using Docker

Tags: docker

**Aim**: I want to see my app running on the outside world.

My **Dockerfile** is as follows:

```
FROM node:8.1.0
RUN mkdir /app 
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
```

`docker build -name xyz .` //ignore any mistakes coz it is working correctly.

`docker run -d -p  8100:3000 --name server xyz`

In order to run this on the user agent i.e chrome, should I write the url as follows?

**ec2 ip:** `xx.xx.xxx.xx:8100` //is it all correct process from top to down?

When I ran  `xx.xx.xxx.xx:8100` on the browser the browser shows the **site can't be reached**.

Comment: Did you open the port in Security groups? Also check if your node server is actually running fine or not using `docker run -it -p  8100:3000 --name server xyz`. Replace `-d` by `-it` so you get logs on the console itself

Comment: Are your port 8100 open on the EC2 instance?

Comment: no i have not opend the port 8100 on EC2 instance, I checked it now, In order to open it asks the type of rule, HTTPS, HTTP defaults to 443 and 80, so which type should I take and in the port range I should give 8100?

Comment: After opening the port 8100 on EC2 I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you missed the part where you need to open the port in the Inbound Rule of the EC2's Security Group. Please see photo below:

[image]

Then go to the port 8100 of your DNS or EC2's IP like **xx.xx.xxx.xx:8100**

Comment: yes I did the same thing but the error is still the same

Comment: could you do a docker ps then update your question with the output of the `docker  ps`?

Comment: after running docker ps  the docker is `up` with ports as `0.0.0.0:8100->3000/tcp`.